# Sorting arrays in c

Tags: c, string, sorting

It is common task to sort an array of integer using qtsort() , but it is possible to sort sort array of strings lets say

```
{"One","two","three","all"}  or even take it higher sort "string number"? e.g
{"50.5>ahoh","45>Two","50>here"}
```

Or are we limited to sorting array of ints?

Comment: In C char is a number in ASCII table. String is an array of char. So you can sort strings. Using the `qsort()` function, the `compare` function that you has to pass as parameter can be the `strcmp`.

Comment: write comparison functions, such as the expected behavior.

Comment: Anything which is comparable in a strong sense can be sorted. This includes strings and "string numbers" from your example. Just implement your criteria in a comparison function. As an optional optimization, you can sort an array of pointers to objects instead of objects themselves. This works especially well when objects are of variable length, such as strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to sort the array of strings lexicographically if you use the following custom comparator that uses `strcmp`:

```
int cmpfunc(void *a, void *b) {
  const char **ia = (const char **)a;
  const char **ib = (const char **)b;
  return strcmp(*ia, *ib);
}

int main() {
   int n;
   char *values[] = { "88", "56", "100", "2", "25" };

   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) 
   {
      printf("%s ", values[n]);
   }

   qsort(values, 5, sizeof(char*), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) 
   {   
      printf("%s ", values[n]);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/VJG10988)

Alternatively, if you want a custom ordering you can define in the same fashion your custom comparator to compare the input strings accordingly.

Comment: is it possible "for whole number"? this is being sorted by first string number and not the whole one